# How do i add database values to a dictionary containing a class as object

Tags: c#, sql-server, xml, linq

I have a dictionary containg a string as TKey and a class "Component" as TValue.
My problem is that a want to add database values and xml values into the class fields.

This is my class Component:

```
public class Component
    {
        public string ComponentNr { get; set; }
        public string Omschrijving { get; set; }
        public int Aantal { get; set; }
        public int Pos { get; set; }
    }
```

I already have filled the fields ComponentNr and Pos with xml attribute values and now i want to get the "Aantal" and "Omschrijving" from the database where Database value "artcode" is ComponentNr

the query:

```
SqlCommand dgCommand = new SqlCommand("select g.artcode, i.Description, sum(g.aantal*-1) as aantal " +
                                                      "from gbkmut g " +
                                                      "join Items i on g.artcode = i.ItemCode " +
                                                      "where 1=1 and g.project=@projectnr and g.reknr=3000 and g.bud_vers='MRP' and g.operation='VOORSMD' and g.artcode !='H MAN' and i.Description not like 'pcb %' " +
                                                      "group by g.artcode, i.Description, g.aantal ", conn);
```

This is what i have at the moment to fill the Dictionary with xml attribute value:

```
Dictionary<string, Component> resultaten = componenten;
List<string> files = fileList;
string file;
file = files.Find(x => x.Contains(faberNr));
XDocument xdoc = XDocument.Load(file);
List<Component> components = xdoc.Descendants("Part").Select(x => new Component()
                    {
                        ComponentNr = (string)x.Elements().Where(y => y.Attribute("PartsName") != null)
                                                            .Select(y => (string)y.Attribute("PartsName")).FirstOrDefault(),
                        Pos = (int)x.Descendants().Where(y => y.Attribute("Setno") != null)
                                                    .Select(y => (int)y.Attribute("Setno")).FirstOrDefault()
                    }).ToList();
                    resultaten = components.GroupBy(x => x.ComponentNr, y => y).ToDictionary(x => x.Key, y => y.FirstOrDefault());
                    return resultaten;
```

Example: 
My expected output is:

```
 Key = 38292000  
 Value = Component 
   Aantal = 16  
   ComponentNr = 38292000 
   Omschrijving = Omschrijving123 
   Pos = 12
```

My actual output is:

```
Key = 38292000 
Value = Component  
 Aantal = 0  
 ComponentNr = 38292000 
 Omschrijving = null  
 Pos = 12
```

Comment: Why would you want the "<br>" ?

Comment: @jdweng it was a typo

Comment: Those are from the database

Comment: Component component = resultaten["38292000"];
             component.Aantal = 16;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, step 1 is to populate a `Dictionary<string, Component>` from xml. Then step 2 is to run a database query to finish filling out the `Component` objects that are stored in the `Dictionary`?

`ComponentNr` is the key into the `Dictionary`, and you have `ComponentNr` from your database query in the `"artcode"` field, so you would just look up the value from the `Dictionary` using `"artcode"` then modify it.

```csharp
// reader is an instance of SqlDataReader you got from the SqlCommand.
// resultaten is the Dictionary<string, Component> that you populated earlier.
// If these columns can be null in the database, don't forget to check them for DBNull.Value.
string componentNr = Convert.ToString(reader["artcode"]);
if (resultaten.TryGetValue(componentNr, out Component value))
{
   value.Aantal = Convert.ToInt32(reader["aantal"]);
   value.Omschrijving = Convert.ToString(reader["Description"]);
}
else
{
   // Component exists in the database but not in the Dictionary.
}
```